# Browser/tab close detection using Javascript (or any other language)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I searched for this question in various places, but all that they mention is the use of Javascript `window.unload` and `window.onbeforeunload`. Also it doesn't work in Chrome most of the times as it gets blocked.

Then how does google manage to do it. If we are composing a mail and by mistake close the tab, google prompts us by a "Are you sure?" box.

Can somebody help me out?

**What actually I want to do is to ask confirmation of the user, when he is filling in the form and by mistake clicks on tab close. If yes, I allow him to navigate away else he stays on the page & continues to fill his form.**

Comment: I do not know if google has another way to detect this. But your both functions mentioned are for this case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested and the example posted on MDN works clearly in Chrome.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Any string';
        }

        // For Safari
        return 'Any string';
    };

    function formSubmit() {
      window.onbeforeunload = null; 
   }
</script>
```

...

```
   <form onsubmit="formSubmit()">...</form>
```

This way a dialog opens that will not be blocked by a popup blocker as it is originated from a user click.

Comment: thanks a lot. :)
still have to learn a lot about js events..
Any good reference for it?

Comment: One more thing. If I have a form in the page, & when the user clicks on submit button, it still asks for confirmation. But I dont want confirmation on form submission. How to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to ask a user if they want to leave the page when they've changed anything in the forms on the page, have a look at [PageHasFormChanges](https://joelpurra.com/projects/pagehasformchanges/). Keep in mind that I developed it for use it on very simple pages, with only one or two forms.

> [PageHasFormChanges](https://joelpurra.com/projects/pagehasformchanges/): A jQuery plugin to check if anything has changed in any form on a page, and warn the user before leaving the page.

You don't need to do anything, but load the script on your page. You can change the defaults though:

```js
JoelPurra.PageHasFormChanges.setOptions({
    leavingPageWarningMessage: "Are you sure?"
});
```

If you're using ajax to submit your forms, you could consider setting `resetWarningOnPreventedSubmit` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

### you can use the [jquery unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) function:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

Comment: this is also blocked by chrome. (as it is equivalent of js onunload).
Anyways thanks, the problem is now solved, thanks to peter.